# How can GCP Automl handle overfitting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a Vertex AI AutoML image classification model. How can I assess it for overfitting? I assume I should be able to compare training vs validation accuracy but these do not seem to be [available](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models).

And if it is overfitting,can I tweak regularization parameters? Is it already doing cross validation? Anything else that can be done? (More data,early stopping, dropouts ie how can these be done?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy it to endpoint and test result with sample images by uploading to endpoint. If it's overfitting you can see the stats in analysis. You can increase the training sample and retrain your model again to get better result.